# Is there a list of ANSI color escape codes somewhere in the standard libraries?

Tags: python, curses, python-curses, ansi-colors, terminfo

I write a lot of little helper scripts, and often these print coloured text in the terminal.  For the simplicity of their packaging and distribution, I often want these little scripts to be without any dependencies.

Hence I'm duplicating data like this a lot in scripts:

```
ansi_colors = {
    None: '\x1b[0m',  # actually black but whatevs
    'red': '\x1b[31m',
    'green' : '\x1b[32m',
    ...
}
```

Does this data exist anywhere in the core libraries?  I dug around and found that `curses` has some `COLOR_*` constants, but they are just integers and it's not obvious how those transform into the ANSI escape codes.

I'm already aware of modules like `termcolor`, `colorama`, `blessings`, so please don't suggest to use those - I want to depend to standard libraries only.

Comment: `man terminfo` is a bit of a help, showing two standard colormaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the man page [`console_codes(4)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html). What you want is the ECMA-48 Set Graphics Rendition:

> The ECMA-48 SGR sequence `ESC [ parameters m` sets display attributes. 
>   Several attributes can be set in the same sequence, separated by
>   semicolons.  An empty parameter (between semicolons or string
>   initiator or terminator)  is
>          interpreted as a zero.
>
> ```
>    param   result
>    0       reset all attributes to their defaults
>    1       set bold
>    2       set half-bright (simulated with color on a color display)
>    4       set  underscore (simulated with color on a color display) (the colors used to
>            simulate dim or underline are set using ESC ] ...)
>    5       set blink
>    7       set reverse video
>    10      reset selected mapping, display control flag, and toggle meta  flag  (ECMA-48
>            says "primary font").
>    11      select  null  mapping,  set  display  control  flag,  reset  toggle meta flag
>            (ECMA-48 says "first alternate font").
>    12      select null mapping, set display control flag, set toggle meta flag  (ECMA-48
>            says "second alternate font").  The toggle meta flag causes the high bit of a
>            byte to be toggled before the mapping table translation is done.
>    21      set normal intensity (ECMA-48 says "doubly underlined")
>    22      set normal intensity
>    24      underline off
>    25      blink off
>    27      reverse video off
>    30      set black foreground
>    31      set red foreground
>    32      set green foreground
>    33      set brown foreground
>    34      set blue foreground
>    35      set magenta foreground
>    36      set cyan foreground
>    37      set white foreground
>    38      set underscore on, set default foreground color
>    39      set underscore off, set default foreground color
>    40      set black background
>    41      set red background
>    42      set green background
>    43      set brown background
>    44      set blue background
>    45      set magenta background
>    46      set cyan background
>    47      set white background
>    49      set default background color
> ```

I don't think they are available as-is in any standard Python module. But if you look carefully, you'll notice that the foreground colors are `30` plus the `curses` constant, while the background colors are `40` plus the `curses` constant. So you can write something like this:

```
import curses
def fcolor(c):
    return '\x1B[{0}m'.format(30 + c)
def bcolor(c):
    return '\x1B[{0}m'.format(40 + c)
def fbcolor(f, b):
    return '\x1B[{0};{1}m'.format(30 + f, 40 + b)

print(fbcolor(curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_YELLOW) + "hello!")
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want.  *ANSI colors* technically refers to the 8-color palette implied by ECMA-48 (ISO-6429) which has named constants in curses.  Libraries don't store escape sequences; those are in a *database*.  For an *ANSI* (sic) terminal, those correspond to escape sequences which *set graphic rendition* (video attributes such as bold, underline, reverse — and color).

termcap, terminfo and curses use a more general notion where you start with a color number and generate the escape sequence which can produce the corresponding color.  Terminals can have no colors, multiple colors (8 for instance, but possibly 16, 88, 256 for xterm and similar terminals).  The information telling how to do this is stored in the terminal database as named *capabilities*.  To set the *ANSI* foreground color, you would use `setaf`, either using a library call or a command-line application such as `tput`, e.g.,

```
tput setaf 4
```

for color 4 (blue).  Simple applications use the low-level termcap or terminfo interfaces, usually with terminfo databases. While you might be inclined to format your own escape sequences, theses interfaces provide formatting functions that let you avoid knowing how many colors a terminal might support.  The terminal database tells your program, using the `TERM` environment variable to select the actual terminal description.  If you have a terminal supporting more than 8 colors, the escape sequence is *not* formed by adding 30 or 40 to the color number.

Here is an example using the low-level terminfo interface from Python:

```
import curses

curses.setupterm()
curses.putp(curses.tparm(curses.tigetstr("setaf"), curses.COLOR_RED))
curses.putp(curses.tparm(curses.tigetstr("setab"), curses.COLOR_YELLOW))
curses.putp("hello!")
curses.putp(curses.tigetstr("sgr0"))
curses.putp("\n")
```

Further reading:

- [15.11. curses — Terminal handling for character-cell displays](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)
- [ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Rodrigo gave a good answer, although the colors are limited to the 8 first colors for foreground. This is my little contribution to handle 16 foreground colors

```
def fcolor(c):
    if c>7:
        return '\x1B[1;{0}m'.format(22 + c)
    else:
        return '\x1B[0;{0}m'.format(30 + c)
def bcolor(c):
    return '\x1B[{0}m'.format(40 + c)
def fbcolor(f, b):
    if f>7:
        return '\x1B[1;{0};{1}m'.format(22 + f, 40 + b)
    else:
        return '\x1B[0;{0};{1}m'.format(30 + f, 40 + b)
```

Comment: I wonder why I got a minus 1 for expanding the previous answer

Comment: +1  from me.  In future it's probably better just to update the existing answer, if you have a minor improvement, rather than posting separate answer.